# read firestore data from another project

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I built an application for ordering food and I want to build another application to read firestore data from it , I did a lot of research but i didn't find a way of doing it.

What i want is that if FireStore gets a new data which is firstName, lastName, area, phoneNumber from the first application I want to read it in the second application, is that possible ?

This is my code

```
   import UIKit
   import Firebase
 
  class infoViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {



@IBOutlet var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var phoneNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var area: UITextField!
    


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
 
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
   
    
    
    
    firstName.delegate = self
    lastName.delegate = self
    phoneNumber.delegate = self
    area.delegate = self
    
    
    let Tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    
    view.addGestureRecognizer(Tap)
    

}




@objc func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)
}




func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}


let db = Firestore.firestore()
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil



@IBAction func checkOut(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    
    
    ref = db.collection("check order").addDocument(data: [
        
        "firstname": firstName.text!,
        "lastname": lastName.text!,
        "area": area.text!,
        "phone": phoneNumber.text!
                   
    ]
    
    )
    
    
    if firstName.text == "" || lastName.text == "" || phoneNumber.text == "" || area.text == "" {
        
  
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please complete your infrmation", preferredStyle: .alert)
        

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler:
                                            nil)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
        
     
        self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
}



}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow.
What do you mean by sending data to different applications? Do you mean different viewcontrollers/classes or actual different iOS apps?

Comment: @LucaSfragara hey, i mean actual different iOS app

Comment: @LucaSfragara i think you get the idea, but is it possible to get notification if there is new data saved in firestore ?

Comment: Try have a look at FireBase triggers https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events. Let me know if the answer I posted is helpful.

Comment: @LucaSfragara yes it is helpful thanks, but the problem is if the firestore received a new data list how can i send it to the second application ?

Comment: You don't really send it. Firestore is just a database and you make request on it. So you would have to make a request to the database every x second and see if there is something new, or you can firebase triggers.

Comment: @LucaSfragara do you have a twitter so can i explain more ?

Comment: Yes, however please keep the discussion here so that it becomes common knowledge. You can edit your answer so that it better explains your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should have the first application to upload the data to firestore. (just create a new document for each upload in a list). Then on the second app do a query on that same list and check for new documents. If there are new documents just fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

You can have have two different apps 'talk' to the same Firebase. Just add the app to the Firestore project in the console and download and install the config.

Suppose you want to write data with App_A and read the data with App_B. It's a simple matter of adding a Firebase Listener (observer) in App_B to the same collection App_A writes it's data to.

See the documentation on [Listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

When data is written from App_A, Firebase will send an event to App_B containing the data that was written so App_B can process it.

If you are looking for any data, just add a listener to the collection which will present any data that was added, changed ro deleted.

If you want to listen for specific data, you can limit the results by adding a query; for example, suppose your user is located in Texas and that user should only be notified of events that occur in Texas.

App_B would add a listener to the same node App_A writes data too and that data should include a field for the state name; then App_B will be listening for any documents that include that state name:

```
db.collection("some_collection").whereField("state", isEqualTo: "Texas")
```

Comment: i think i found what i want which is cloud firestore triggers https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events but the problem is im new in development and i don't know how to use node.js in swift.